# Query Firebase On Spinner

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I have a problem with my code I want to use the value event listner to show the listview but when I pass the spinner it does not show

========================== QUERY ======================================

```
//SELECIONANDO PELO GENERO
    filtersamba = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artistas")
            .orderByChild("artistaGenero")
            .equalTo("Samba");
```

========================== Event Value ================================

```
 ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        artistaList.clear();
        //onDataChange usado para ler toda hora a database;
        for(DataSnapshot artistaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Artista artista = artistaSnapshot.getValue(Artista.class);

            artistaList.add(artista);
        }

        ListaArtistas adpter = new ListaArtistas(HomeActivity.this,artistaList);
        listViewArtistas.setAdapter(adpter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

====================== OnStart Show Event ================================

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   final String escolhido = selectFiltro.getSelectedItem().toString();
   selectFiltro.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           if (escolhido == "Samba") {
               filtersamba.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
           }
           if (escolhido == "Todos") {
               filterTodos();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });

}
```

Comment: Please post full code and explain properly what is not working.

Comment: Dont have space for full code but this full code  https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/ i try filter listview but dont work  onStart when i put just this databaseArtista.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener); work

Comment: Please provide the values of Spinner i don't see any setadapter or value attach to spinner

Comment: I put values on String <array name="filtro">
        <item>Todos</item>
        <item>Rock</item>
        <item>Samba</item>
        <item>Eletronica</item>
    </array> 
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerFiltro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/filtro">

        </Spinner>

Comment: I send photos for you see my intention sry my english wait a minute

Comment: Here we go  this first photo show all post https://i.imgur.com/tnAJMG7.jpeg
second photo show just Samba category https://i.imgur.com/pqMWvnk.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

====================================OnStart=========================================

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    filterList();
}
```

==================================Method=================================================

```
private void filterList(){
    selectFiltro.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            boolean todos = selectFiltro.getSelectedItem().equals("Todos");
            boolean rock  = selectFiltro.getSelectedItem().equals("Rock");
            boolean samba = selectFiltro.getSelectedItem().equals("Samba");
            boolean eletronica = selectFiltro.getSelectedItem().equals("Eletronica");

            if (todos) {
                databaseArtista.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
            } else if (samba) {
                filtersamba.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
            } else if (rock) {
                filterrock.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
            } else if (eletronica) {
                filtereletronica.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
            } else {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Algo deu Errado!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```